# Is this a valid OSPF topology?

Tags: routing, router, ospf, design, topology

In the following topology:

- every Backbone router is an ABR.
- Router 2 belongs to three different areas, area 0, area 1, and area 4.

is this a valid topology for OSPF ? it works as expected and it shows no misbehavior. however I can't find a reference to such topology anywhere on the internet.

[image]

Comment: Now it's on the Internet. ;-)  But seriously, it's fine.

Comment: The topology is fine, but the lines defining the area borders should go *through an ABR*, not through the links connecting the ABR to the other area's routers.  With OSPF, you cannot have different areas at either end of a link. A router becomes an ABR when it has (at least) one interface in Area 0 and (at least) one interface in a non-zero area - hence the area border is *within* the ABR. 
This might seem nitpicking, but once you start with BGP, you'll see that things are different over there, in exactly this aspect.

Comment: Thank you Marc and Ron for your comments!. I am aware that lines should go through the ABR, however I have drawn the lines quickly with a mouse so I couldn't afford to be that accurate :)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Comment: I accepted the only answer at this time.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The main thing with OSPF is that every area is connected via a link to area 0, barring that a virtual link and that is accomplished here despite the shakey drawings of the circles surrounding each area, let's be thankful you aren't performing surgery.